# USB Printer: unable to enumerate USB

Tags: 14.04, usb, printing

I have issues getting my canon MP540 to work on my 14.04 machine.
They Printer is not recoginzed at all.
`tail -f /var/log/syslog` when plugging in:

```
May 15 21:18:53 Notebook kernel: [ 1218.970245] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
May 15 21:18:53 Notebook kernel: [ 1218.970459] usb 2-2: Device not responding to set address.
May 15 21:18:58 Notebook kernel: [ 1224.188379] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/all, error -110
May 15 21:18:58 Notebook kernel: [ 1224.300326] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
May 15 21:18:58 Notebook kernel: [ 1224.316857] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -71
May 15 21:18:58 Notebook kernel: [ 1224.437007] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/all, error -71
May 15 21:18:58 Notebook kernel: [ 1224.548231] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
May 15 21:18:58 Notebook kernel: [ 1224.565084] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/all, error -71
May 15 21:18:58 Notebook kernel: [ 1224.732172] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
May 15 21:18:58 Notebook kernel: [ 1224.732582] usb 2-2: Device not responding to set address.
May 15 21:18:59 Notebook kernel: [ 1224.936330] usb 2-2: Device not responding to set address.
May 15 21:18:59 Notebook kernel: [ 1225.140031] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 15, error -71
May 15 21:18:59 Notebook kernel: [ 1225.140098] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
```

The problems persits on all USB-Ports, but the printer works fine with windows.

Comment: This question is specific to Canon printers and *not* specific to Ubuntu at all. Consider moving it to "Unix & Linux".

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue with Canon LBP3010 printer. It turned out that after some time being powered on, the printer would put itself into a different state where its USB connection no longer works. Not sure why, but *what helped in my case was to just restart the printer.* Simply reconnecting the USB cable would *not* help, because the printer would still remain in that weird state.

I have tried it on Linux kernels 4.9 and 4.12, on 3 different computers including Raspberry Pi 3 model B. None of them would even recognize the printer as an USB device after it has put itself into this weird state. There were just errors of the following kind:

- `Device not responding to setup address`
- `device not accepting address`
- and eventually `unable to enumerate USB device`

I suspect it is a consequence of Canon printers implementing some kind of power saving mode where they also disable the printer's USB interface.